# why jquery core file is still not default added in browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

I was wondering: scripting with javascript jquery is used by millions of people. Jquery is a well known coding language. Why the core file is still not default present in all the browsers?

So you dont have to put this line

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

in the head of your webpage anymore.

Can someone give me a good reason for that?

Comment: I'll give you several. 1) not all websites need/use javascript. 2) Nothing jQuery does can not be done in some other way with javascript. 3) There are javascript frameworks that are not compatible with jQuery.

Comment: why voted -2 already. Is this a really bad question?

Comment: JQuery ..? What is that?

Comment: @mudraya It's voted -2 already because this isn't even a valid question for this site. I'm surprised it's not closed yet.

Comment: @gforce301 Then tell me: what makes a question valid?

Comment: @mudraya Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Why don't they include 1000s of other libraries too? Browser cache basically does what you ask when you use a CDN. Download once and it sits there.

Comment: Oke. I just registered and i asked a question that seems not been valid for this forum. And now i can see, i am not been able to ask another question. I even have no influence on my negative voting. So this seems to be the first and last question i can ask on this forum. Strange forum with NOT user friendly rules...The marketing startegy seems to be more important then really helping people with a question

Comment: @mudraya 1) you can delete the question, especially since you know it's not a valid question. 2) you could have read the rules for posting here before asking the question. 3) in the realm of all the possible questions that could be asked here, how important really was this one? "The marketing startegy seems to be more important then really helping people with a question". How much help did you really need with this? Was any answer to this going to make or break something you were working on? I think not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQUERY is currently 82.34 KB (minified), everyone may not use JQUERY in their projects so having the unnecessary file load onto your server is a waste. Another reason is security since they are always finding vulnerabilities in JQUERY and needing to patch or update. It should be the users overall decision whether they add it in or not.